# Trouble With Control Sizing - Why Do I Get Different Behavior in IE VS. FireFox/Chrome

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, firefox

My Silverlight 'window' appears larger in Internet Explorer than it does in FireFox or Chrome....and I can't seem to figure out why.  My .HTML file is essentially empty (VS.Net generated code).  Below you can see that I set the Width to 800px and the Height to 600px.

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="800px" height="600px" >
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/myTest.xap"/>
<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="background" value="white" />
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
    <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
</a>
```

In FireFox and Chrome, I get a Window that is exactly 800px by 600px.  In IE, when it finishes loading, there is a brief flicker of the 800x600 window; but after that initial second, it enlarges.  It's not full screen, but it's 'stretched' to be bigger.  Everything inside my game scales and it works (I actually prefer the scaled up affect in IE) just as well....but I really want the same behavior between all browsers.  At the very least, I'd like to understand what's going on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found someone with the exact same problem here:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/159458/358297.aspx

As it turns out, we both had the 'zoom' in IE turned on.  I must have hit cntrl+mouse wheel at some point and never set it back.

Sorry